# Adding scores to a scoreboard after the game ends using sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-database

i made a quiz game which asks some questions to the player and if wrong answer is clicked or if the questions are completed, the game ends displaying the score in an alert dialog.
what i want to further do is, get all the scores of the games played and add it to a score board and display the scores from high to low, and append the socres as new game is played everytime. im trying to make a table in database using sqlite. but i dont know how to link the scores to that database class and add them into the scoreboard.

> This is the main game activity. All the code regarding the game is here

```
package com.example.sudhe.quizgame3;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4;

    ImageView QuestionImage;

    TextView score;

    List<CountryItem> list;


    private int mScore = 0;

    Random r;

    int turn = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        r = new Random();

        QuestionImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.QuestionImage);

        answer1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        answer2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        answer3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        answer4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answer4);

        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

        score.setText("Score: " + mScore);



        list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0; i < new DataBase().answers.length; i++){
            list.add(new CountryItem(new DataBase().answers[i], new DataBase().flags[i]));
        }

        Collections.shuffle(list);

        newQuestion(turn);

        answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (answer1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(turn - 1).getName())){
                    mScore++;
                    score.setText("Score: " + mScore);

                    if (turn < list.size()){
                        turn++;
                        newQuestion(turn);
                    }else{
                        gameOver();

                    }
                }else {
                    gameOver();
                }

            }
        });
        answer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (answer2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(turn - 1).getName())){
                    mScore++;
                    score.setText("Score: " + mScore);

                    if (turn < list.size()){
                        turn++;
                        newQuestion(turn);
                    }else{
                        gameOver();
                    }
                }else {
                    gameOver();
                }

            }
        });
        answer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (answer3.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(turn - 1).getName())){
                    mScore++;
                    score.setText("Score: " + mScore);

                    if (turn < list.size()){
                        turn++;
                        newQuestion(turn);
                    }else{
                        gameOver();
                    }
                }else {
                    gameOver();
                }

            }
        });
        answer4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (answer4.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(turn - 1).getName())){
                    mScore++;
                    score.setText("Score: " + mScore);

                    if (turn < list.size()){
                        turn++;
                        newQuestion(turn);
                    }else{
                        gameOver();
                    }
                }else {
                    gameOver();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void newQuestion(int number){
        QuestionImage.setImageResource(list.get(number - 1).getImage());

        int correct_answer = r.nextInt(4) + 1;

        int firstButton = number - 1;
        int secondButton;
        int thirdButton;
        int fourthButton;

        switch (correct_answer){
            case 1:
                answer1.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());

                do{
                    secondButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                }while (secondButton == firstButton);
                do{
                    thirdButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                }while (thirdButton == secondButton || thirdButton == firstButton);
                do{
                    fourthButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                }while (fourthButton == thirdButton || fourthButton == secondButton || fourthButton == firstButton);

                answer2.setText(list.get(secondButton).getName());
                answer3.setText(list.get(thirdButton).getName());
                answer4.setText(list.get(fourthButton).getName());

                break;
            case 2:
                answer2.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());

                do{
                    secondButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                }while (secondButton == firstButton);
                do{
                    thirdButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                }while (thirdButton == secondButton || thirdButton == firstButton);
                do{
                    fourthButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                }while (fourthButton == thirdButton || fourthButton == secondButton || fourthButton == firstButton);

                answer1.setText(list.get(secondButton).getName());
                answer3.setText(list.get(thirdButton).getName());
                answer4.setText(list.get(fourthButton).getName());

                break;
            case 3:
                answer3.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());

                do{
                    secondButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                }while (secondButton == firstButton);
                do{
                    thirdButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                }while (thirdButton == secondButton || thirdButton == firstButton);
                do{
                    fourthButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                }while (fourthButton == thirdButton || fourthButton == secondButton || fourthButton == firstButton);

                answer2.setText(list.get(secondButton).getName());
                answer1.setText(list.get(thirdButton).getName());
                answer4.setText(list.get(fourthButton).getName());

                break;
            case 4:
                answer4.setText(list.get(firstButton).getName());

                do{
                    secondButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                }while (secondButton == firstButton);
                do{
                    thirdButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                }while (thirdButton == secondButton || thirdButton == firstButton);
                do{
                    fourthButton = r.nextInt(list.size());
                }while (fourthButton == thirdButton || fourthButton == secondButton || fourthButton == firstButton);

                answer2.setText(list.get(secondButton).getName());
                answer3.setText(list.get(thirdButton).getName());
                answer1.setText(list.get(fourthButton).getName());

                break;
        }


    }
    private void gameOver(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Game Over! Your Score is " + mScore + "points.")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("NEW GAME",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("EXIT",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }


}
```

> This is score class

```
 package com.example.sudhe.quizgame3;

    /**
     * Created by sudhe on 19-05-2017.
     */

    public class Score {

        int id;
        String game_score;

        public Score(int i, String string, String cursorString){

        }

        public Score( String game_score){
            this.game_score = game_score;
        }

        public Score(int id, String game_score){
            this.id = id;
            this.game_score = game_score;
        }

        public Score() {

        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getGame_score() {
            return game_score;
        }

        public void setGame_score(String game_score) {
            this.game_score = game_score;
        }
    }
```

> This is the database i created using sqlite

```
package com.example.sudhe.quizgame3;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by sudhe on 19-05-2017.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scoreManager";
    private static final String TABLE_SCORE = "score_table";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_SCORE = "score";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_SCORE_TABLE ="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORE + " (" +
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_SCORE + " TEXT"
                + ")";

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addScore(Score score){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_SCORE, score.getGame_score());

        db.insert(TABLE_SCORE, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    Score getScore(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SCORE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_SCORE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        Score score =  new Score(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1));
        return score;
    }

    public List<Score> getAllScores(){
        List<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Score score = new Score();
                score.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                score.setGame_score(cursor.getString(1));

                scoreList.add(score);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return scoreList;
    }
    public int updatescore(Score score){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_SCORE, score.getGame_score());

        return db.update(TABLE_SCORE, values, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(score.getId())});
    }
    public void deletescore(Score score){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_SCORE, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(score.getId())});
        db.close();
    }

    public int getScoreCount(){
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FORM " + TABLE_SCORE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        return cursor.getCount();
    }
}
```

> **This is the scoreboard activity i created to display the score. This is where im stuck. I dont know how to add the score from game activity to this.**

```
package com.example.sudhe.quizgame3;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ScoreBoard extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;

    String text = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score_board);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        db.addScore(new Score());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It looks as though, to add the scores to the table, add them from within the `gameOver` method in the `MainActivity` using the two lines of code `DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this); and `db.addScore(mScore);` (when adding a new score, similar for updating an existing). In ScoreBoard you'd do the same but using something like  `List<Score> scorelist = getAllScores()`.